# SQLite.Net Extensions with Many-To-One doesn't work as expected

Tags: c#, many-to-one, sqlite-net, sqlite-net-extensions, sqlite.net

My table will contain many repeating strings like domains. For minimize database size I want save only unique domains in other table and use domains id in main table.

All times I did it manually, but a short time ago I found out SQLite can did it automatically.

Now I try use Many-To-One relationship with "FOREIGN" key, but without success.
Maybe I do something wrong.

**Example code**

Tables classes:

```
public class Domains
{
    public Domains() { }
    public Domains(string domain) { this.Domain = domain; }

    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Unique, MaxLength(64)]
    public string Domain { get; set; }
}

public class Statistics
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Timestamp { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(typeof(Domains))]
    public int DomainId { get; set; }

    public int Status { get; set; }

    [ManyToOne(CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.All)]
    public Domains Domain { get; set; }
}
```

Main code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var dbFile = "stats.db";
    var domains = new[] { "stackoverflow.com", "superuser.com", "serverfault.com", "google.com", "microsoft.com" };
    var statList = new List<Statistics>();

    var sqlBase = new SQLiteConnection(dbFile);
    sqlBase.Execute("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON");
    sqlBase.CreateTable<Domains>();
    sqlBase.CreateTable<Statistics>();

    Console.WriteLine(SQLite3.LibVersionNumber());

    var runTimestamp = (int)(DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalSeconds;
    foreach (var domain in domains)
    {
        HttpWebResponse resp = null;
        var status = -1;
        try
        {
            resp = (HttpWebResponse)WebRequest.Create("http://" + domain).GetResponse();
        }
        catch { };
        status = (int)resp.StatusCode;

        var stat = new Statistics();
        stat.Domain = new Domains(domain);
        stat.Status = status;
        stat.Timestamp = runTimestamp;

        statList.Add(stat);
    }

    sqlBase.InsertOrIgnoreAllWithChildren(statList); // Modification "INSERT" with "OR IGNORE"

    Console.WriteLine(@"Table ""Domains""");
    foreach (var table in sqlBase.Table<Domains>())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Id: {0}\tDomain: {1}", table.Id, table.Domain);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();

    Console.WriteLine(@"Table ""Statistics""");
    foreach (var table in sqlBase.Table<Statistics>())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Id: {0}\tDomain Id: {1}", table.Id, table.DomainId);
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

After first run it's look fine.

[image: First Run]

But after second run, when domains repeated - sqlite extensions insert wrong domains id

[image: Second Run]

Where I make mistake?

Comment: Can you post your `InsertOrIgnoreAllWithChildren` code?

Comment: I just replace conn.Insert(element); on conn.Insert(element, "OR IGNORE"); in function InsertElement() from SQLite.Net.Extensions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake, the feature "Foreign key" does not work as I thought.
So I use view with join two tables and triggers for edit view.

And it works as I need it.

SQLite.Net and SQLite.Net.Extensions doesn't support views and triggers, so I use only SQLite.Net and Execute-function for create view and triggers.

```
CREATE VIEW IF NOT EXISTS 'StatisticsView' AS 
  SELECT Stat.Id, Stat.Timestamp, Dom.Domain, Stat.Status FROM Statistics AS Stat 
    INNER JOIN Domains Dom ON Stat.DomainId = Dom.Id

CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS 'StatisticsViewInsert'
INSTEAD OF INSERT ON 'StatisticsView'
BEGIN
  INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Domains(Domain) VALUES(NEW.Domain);
  INSERT INTO Statistics(Timestamp, Status, DomainId) VALUES (NEW.Timestamp, NEW.Status, (SELECT Id FROM Domains WHERE Domain = NEW.Domain));
END

CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS 'StatisticsViewUpdate' 
INSTEAD OF UPDATE ON 'StatisticsView' 
BEGIN
  INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Domains(Domain) VALUES(NEW.Domain);
  UPDATE Statistics SET Status = NEW.Status, Timestamp = NEW.Timestamp, DomainId = (SELECT Id FROM Domains WHERE Domain = NEW.Domain) WHERE Id = OLD.Id;
END

CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS 'StatisticsViewDelete' 
INSTEAD OF DELETE ON 'StatisticsView' 
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM Domains WHERE (Domain = OLD.Domain AND (SELECT COUNT(Id) FROM Statistics WHERE DomainId = (SELECT Id FROM Domains WHERE Domain = OLD.Domain)) < 2);
  DELETE FROM Statistics WHERE Id=OLD.Id;
END
```

Tables classes:

```
public class Domains
{
    public Domains() { }
    public Domains(string domain) { this.Domain = domain; }

    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Unique, MaxLength(64)]
    public string Domain { get; set; }
}

public class Statistics
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Timestamp { get; set; }
    public int DomainId { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
}

// Virtual Table
public class StatisticsView
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Timestamp { get; set; }
    public string Domain { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
}
```

Main code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var dbFile = "stats.db";
    var domains = new[] { "stackoverflow.com", "superuser.com", "serverfault.com", "google.com", "microsoft.com" };
    var statList = new List<StatisticsView>();

    var sqlBase = new SQLiteConnection(dbFile);
    sqlBase.CreateTable<Domains>();
    sqlBase.CreateTable<Statistics>();
    sqlBase.Execute("CREATE VIEW IF NOT EXISTS 'StatisticsView' AS SELECT Stat.Id, Stat.Timestamp, Dom.Domain, Stat.Status FROM Statistics AS Stat INNER JOIN Domains Dom ON Stat.DomainId=Dom.Id;");
    sqlBase.Execute("CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS 'StatisticsViewInsert' INSTEAD OF INSERT ON 'StatisticsView' BEGIN INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Domains(Domain) VALUES(NEW.Domain); INSERT INTO Statistics(Timestamp, Status, DomainId) VALUES (NEW.Timestamp, NEW.Status, (SELECT Id FROM Domains WHERE Domain=NEW.Domain)); END");
    sqlBase.Execute("CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS 'StatisticsViewUpdate' INSTEAD OF UPDATE ON 'StatisticsView' BEGIN INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Domains(Domain) VALUES(NEW.Domain); UPDATE Statistics SET Status=NEW.Status, Timestamp=NEW.Timestamp, DomainId=(SELECT Id FROM Domains WHERE Domain=NEW.Domain) WHERE Id=OLD.Id; END");
    sqlBase.Execute("CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS 'StatisticsViewDelete' INSTEAD OF DELETE ON 'StatisticsView' BEGIN DELETE FROM Domains WHERE (Domain = OLD.Domain AND (SELECT COUNT(Id) FROM Statistics WHERE DomainId=(SELECT Id FROM Domains WHERE Domain=OLD.Domain)) < 2); DELETE FROM Statistics WHERE Id=OLD.Id; END");

    Console.WriteLine(SQLite3.LibVersionNumber());

    var runTimestamp = (int)(DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalSeconds;
    foreach (var domain in domains)
    {
        HttpWebResponse resp = null;
        var status = -1;
        try
        {
            resp = (HttpWebResponse)WebRequest.Create("http://" + domain).GetResponse();
        }
        catch { };
        status = (int)resp.StatusCode;

        var stat = new StatisticsView();
        stat.Domain = domain;
        stat.Status = status;
        stat.Timestamp = runTimestamp;

        statList.Add(stat);
    }

    sqlBase.InsertAll(statList);

    Console.WriteLine(@"Table ""Domains""");
    foreach (var table in sqlBase.Table<Domains>())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Id: {0}\tDomain: {1}", table.Id, table.Domain);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();

    Console.WriteLine(@"Table ""Statistics""");
    foreach (var table in sqlBase.Table<Statistics>())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Id: {0}\tDomain Id: {1}", table.Id, table.DomainId);
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

After second run:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In your code you're creating new `Domains` entities every time you try to save new stats.

SQLite-Net Extensions needs the primary key of the referenced object in order to assign the foreign key. It seems that your `InsertOrIgnoreAllWithChildren` is assigning `10` to all your `Domains` objects even when they're not being inserted.

What you need to do is fetch your current domains in order to get the correct primary key.

Try something like this:

```
var dbFile = "stats.db";
var statList = new List<Statistics>();

var sqlBase = new SQLiteConnection(dbFile);
sqlBase.Execute("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON");
sqlBase.CreateTable<Domains>();
sqlBase.CreateTable<Statistics>();

// Fetch existing domains from database
var domains = sqlBase.Table<Domains>().toList();

if (domains.isEmpty()) {
    // Insert domains into database if they don't exist
    var domainNames = new[] { "stackoverflow.com", "superuser.com", "serverfault.com", "google.com", "microsoft.com" };
    domains = domainNames.Select(domainName => new Domain(domainName));
    sqlBase.InsertAll(domains);
}

var runTimestamp = (int)(DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalSeconds;
foreach (var domain in domains)
{
    HttpWebResponse resp = null;
    var status = -1;
    try
    {
        resp = (HttpWebResponse)WebRequest.Create("http://" + domain.domain).GetResponse();
    }
    catch { };
    status = (int)resp.StatusCode;

    var stat = new Statistics();
    stat.Domain = domain; // Assign the existing domain object
    stat.Status = status;
    stat.Timestamp = runTimestamp;

    statList.Add(stat);
}

// Insert only Statistics (Domains already exist), and assign foreign keys
sqlBase.InsertAllWithChildren(statList);
```

Comment: It's what I did before manually.
Why use foreign keys, if it can't check for existence and insert automatically?

Comment: Seems SQLite.Net.Extensions not use feautures from sqlite >= 3.6.19 "FOREIGN KEY" and "REFERENCE" just emulate it. I found NET.Sqlite - modification of SQLite.NET with real "foreign key" and other relationship features. I try use it https://github.com/daynin/net-sqlite

Comment: Yes, SQLite.net doesn't support `FOREIGN KEY` so SQLite-Net Extensions emulates it. In this simple scenario using plain SQLite.net methods will be easy. In more complex hierarchy trees using SQLite-Net Extensions will help reduce a lot of boilerplate

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Domain` as primary (and foreign) key and your current code will work as expected:

```
public class Domains
{
    public Domains() { }
    public Domains(string domain) { this.Domain = domain; }

    [PrimaryKey, MaxLength(64)]
    public string Domain { get; set; }
}

public class Statistics
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Timestamp { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(typeof(Domains))]
    public String DomainId { get; set; }

    public int Status { get; set; }

    [ManyToOne(CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.All)]
    public Domains Domain { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: In this example, there is no sense from the Domains-table and it is redundant. I want minimize database size but many repeating string only expand it. Domains can be thousands.